# Substitute letters and numbers with random characters in a string

Tags: java, string

I want to anonymise a string (an arbitrary input from users) but still keep its structure. Thus, I want to substitute lower-case letters with random lower-case letters, numbers with random numbers and upper-case letters with random upper-case letters.

I've come up with this function but I was wondering if this is the fastest/best possible way?

```
public String anonymiseString(String originalInput){
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(originalInput);
    Random r = new Random();
    char currentChar;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        currentChar = input.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isUpperCase(currentChar))
            input.setCharAt(i, (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'A'));
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(currentChar))
            input.setCharAt(i, (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
        else if (Character.isDigit(currentChar))
            input.setCharAt(i, (char) (r.nextInt(10) + '0'));
    }

    return input.toString();
}
```

An example can be run here: https://ideone.com/VNebO0

Comment: While this question could attract good answer as-is, it would have been better received on the [CodeReview stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since you are presenting working code you wish to improve.

Comment: Did you figure out why you never get a nine in your result strings?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is mostly working, apart from a tiny mistake that is not at the heart of the question. Working code should be posted to the codereview site.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I do now and although I get your point I do believe there is a more efficient way to point out errors without sarcasm. But thanks!

Comment: @Julio This was no sarcasm, I just didn't want to spoil an a-ha moment for you. This is a very common and hard-to-find mistake that I can almost guarantee you wouldn't make again :-) Another thing you may want to fix is hard-coding of Unicode code points 65, 97, and 48: `'A'` is easier for human readers to understand than 65, even though compilers do not care one way or the other.

Comment: I see, sometimes getting the right meaning from text messages is difficult. Anyways, just changed the hard-coding numbers. Thanks, it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Basically your solution is good but there were some ways to make the code more clean:

- move new char generations into 3 separate methods (e.g. `char createNewUpperCase()`, `char createNewDigit()` and `char createNewLetter()`)
- extract all `if` logic into separate method too (e.g. `char createNewChar(char currentChar)`)

In this way your code will be better from [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) side.